# The best way to implement a SIP + VoIP client for blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, voip, sip

- How to implement a SIP/VoIP client for Blackberry smart phones?
- Where to begin?  Should I start with [MjSip](http://www.mjsip.org/)?
- Is there any sample code available specific for Blackberry?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is blackberry has no native SIP or VoIP API so development requires the use of external API's for development. And that is rather problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try PJSIP.

[PJSIP](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/BB10) is a free and open source multimedia stack written in C and it supports audio, video, presence and instant messaging capabilities.

You can refers other links also as [link1](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/07/voip-development-on-blackberry-10/) [link2](http://blog.truphone.com/2012/04/the-blackberry-jam-in-our-donut.html), [PDF](http://www.pjsip.org/release/0.5.4/PJSIP-Dev-Guide.pdf).

Comment: Please take more care when reviewing suggested edits, [such as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1154068); this is an obvious question being asked in the edit, and should have been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider http://sip-communicator.org/ or JAIN SIP.

Answer (score 0):

Try linphone
http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html